# College not showing on College Scorecard

Tags: collegescorecard

The college I am IR director for does not show on the College Scorecard web site. It does not show by zip code, state or name search. Data do show for the college in the raw data file. An answer to a prior question about missing colleges indicates the Scorecard is currrently "limited to institutions that predominantly grant 2-year and/or 4-year degrees. The Department of Education is exploring whether and how to add predominantly less-than-two-year schools that offer associate’s or bachelor’s degree programs to the site in future iterations of Scorecard." My college grants predominantly associate's degrees. Other colleges in the state system (NC) are displayed. Why wouldn't our college be showing?

Answer (score 3):

Predominant degree is calculated by the most common category of award conferred by the institution, calculated from counts of awards included in the IPEDS Completions component. Based on that specific definition, does your institution still fit in that associate degree category? Is so, if you provide the school's UNITID, OPEID or name, that could help me find the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Brian is correct, but also note that this criteria appears to be arbitrary and undocumented. One result is that only 6 of 13 community colleges in Colorado are included in the Scorecard.
http://mfeldstein.com/17-of-community-colleges-are-not-included-in-college-scorecard/

Comment: The Department recently added institutions to the consumer site such that institutions that predominantly award certificates (PREDDEG=1) are included IF the highest degree is at least an Associate's (HIGHDEG>=2 ) AND the institution offers an associate's or bachelor's degree (CIPxxASSOC>0 OR CIPxxBACHL>0)